# Cast collectionviewsource to list in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, collectionviewsource

I have static method where i need to pass the values of the filtered collectionviewsource but at present i am unable to do so . I tried various methods to cast it to list but i was unable to adapt to the static method.

ViewModel - Static Method

```
static public List<string> getallcrsp()
    {
        List<string> data =  new List<string>();
        data.Add("TEST1");
        data.Add("TEST2");
        return data;
    }
```

ViewModel - Collectionviewsource Method - AllCRSP is a collectionviewsource and i want this to be converted to list and pass its value to the static method.

```
        public void Updateswlist()
    {

        CRmappings2 = new ObservableCollection<SPFetchCREntity>(crentities.ToList());
        AllCRSP = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CRmappings2);
        SearchMU = SelectedSW.SW_Version;
        AllCRSP.Filter = obj =>
        {
            SPFetchCREntity entity = obj as SPFetchCREntity;
            return obj != null && entity.SW_Version == SearchMU.ToString();
        };
        AllCRSP.Refresh();
        Isdrawopen = false;
        SelectedTabIndex = 0;
        Isselected = false;
        Isselected = true;
    }
```

Comment: @mjwills No, It didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `CollectionViewSource` of `SPFetchCREntity` objects and want a `List<string>` you should do this:

```
using System.Linq;

// 1. Get source collection of the CollectionViewSource
IEnumerable source = AllCRSP.SourceCollection;

// 2. Make it generic using Linq OfType<> method 
IEnumerable<SPFetchCREntity> source_typed = source.OfType<SPFetchCREntity>();

// 3. You can filter your list using Linq Where method
IEnumerable<SPFetchCREntity> source_typed_filtered = source_typed.Where(obj => obj != null && entity.SW_Version == SearchMU.ToString());

// 4. Get string equivalent of your objects using Linq Select method
IEnumerable<string> source_string = source_typed_filtered.Select(obj => <...something like obj.ToString()...>);

// 5. Convert it ToList using Linq
List<string> list = source_string.ToList();
```

Or in a brief sentence

```
var list = AllCRSP.SourceCollection.OfType<SPFetchCREntity>().Where(...).Select(...).ToList();
```